# Integration between google maps and django

Tags: django, api, google-maps-api-3, python-requests

I 'm working on a django app based on location where I 've a model shop like this :

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = gis_models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude",
                                     geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

suppose that in my views i 've a function that filter the db based on a location (long , lat) and rener nearby shops  , i will use google maps api here to render a map and show center based on the sent (long , lat) and markers for the nearby shops , now i want to enable the user to change the location on the map by drag and set a new center  and listen to this in my view to run filter again and apply changes ? any help for this , thanks .